# Разделение столбца при определенной строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Не понимаю как сделать разделение столбца при определенной строке.
Есть набор данных в виде:

```
|**Stage 1**|     |
|-----------|-----|         
|50.0       |4.67 | 
|100.0      |4.80 |     
|**Stage 2**|     |     
|50.0       |-4.67| 
|100.0      |-4.80|
|**Stage 3**|     |         
|50.0       |4.67 | 
|100.0      |4.80 |
```

Нужно чтобы стало:

```
|Stage 1|       |Stage 2|       |Stage 3|     |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|
|50.0   |4.67   |50.0   |-4.67  |50.0   |4.67 | 
|100.0  |4.80   |100.0  |-4.80  |100.0  |4.80 |
```

Количество Stage`й  может быть > 100. Как можно автоматизировать данный процесс на python, может быть использовать pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так вот линейно "в лоб" можно решить:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = '''
|**Stage 1**|     |
|-----------|-----|         
|50.0       |4.67 | 
|100.0      |4.80 |     
|**Stage 2**|     |     
|50.0       |-4.67| 
|100.0      |-4.80|
|**Stage 3**|     |         
|50.0       |4.67 | 
|100.0      |4.80 |   
'''.split('\n')

d = defaultdict(str)
i = 0
savediv = ""

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        if '**' in line:
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1

        if i == 1:
            if '--' in line:
                savediv = line[1:]
            else:
                d[i] += savediv
                i += 1
        if d[i]:
            line = line[1:]    
        d[i] += line

for line in d.values():
    print(line)
```

Вывод:

```
|**Stage 1**|     |**Stage 2**|     |**Stage 3**|     |
|-----------|-----|-----------|-----|-----------|-----|
|50.0       |4.67 |50.0       |-4.67|50.0       |4.67 |
|100.0      |4.80 |100.0      |-4.80|100.0      |4.80 |
```